# JavaScript date function returns "Date {Invalid Date}" in Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, datetime, unobtrusive-javascript, ecmascript-5

Facing a problem with `JavaScript Date` function, `returns "Date {Invalid Date}"` in Firefox browser but works fine in Google chrome.

```
// My Input is
new Date("Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 1");

// Works fine in google chrome 
// Result: Mon Jan 01 2001 10:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

// Not working in Firefox (Version: 15.0.1)
// Result: Date {Invalid Date}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) does not take a timezone parameter in that way. My thought is that Chrome is just ignoring it.

```
new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond])
```

Please see @Brett's comment below for more information.

Comment: It does allow it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: It refers to RFC 2822 which says "Though some of these syntactic forms MUST NOT be generated according to the grammar in section 3, they MUST be accepted and parsed by a conformant receiver...The syntax for the obsolete date format...allows for a list of alphabetic time zone specifications that were used in earlier versions of this standard...EST" I put the link for sake of reference to a string argument being allowed. Spec appears to require a month, day, and year, and nothing should be after "EST". Also seems should be comma after day of week, but Firefox doesn't complain either.

Comment: Ah, well I appreciate you putting it here then as it definitely helps explain the cause.

Answer (score 5):

This works in all browsers -

> new Date('2001/01/31 12:00:00 AM')

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the parameter is RFC1123 compliant: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123