# Javascript Date can not support in firefox browser

Tags: javascript

```
 var time_in = data[i].timeIn;//data[i].timeIn= 2015-04-18 1:00:30
 time_in = new Date(time_in);
```

In Firefox, the result of `time_in` in console is → `Date {Invalid Date}`.

In Chrome, the result of `time_in` in console is → `Sat Apr 18 2015 01:00:30 GMT+0630 (Myanmar Standard Time)`

Comment: what does data contain?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo See the comment in his code example. Use `new Date("2015-04-18 1:00:30")` to test.

Comment: Have a look at these posts,

[StackOverflow explanation][1]

[Another explanation in stackoverflow][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257460/new-date-is-working-in-chrome-but-not-firefox
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822225/javascript-date-function-returns-date-invalid-date-in-firefox-browser

Comment: If you want all browsers to parse the date correctly use a ISO 8601 formatted date or use a date parser like [moment js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Answer (score 3):

The date you have given as a parameter *is* invalid, though browsers *may* try to interpret it either way.

You should use either RFC2822, or ISO 8601 format instead, it works better in cross-browser situations. For example, this would be a date in ISO 8601 format:

```
2015-04-18T01:00:30+0630
```

By the way, the ISO 8601 format *must be* valid in an ECMAScript 5 complaint environment.

Comment: This is the correct answer and not just do `new Date(year,month,...)` .stick to _UNIVERSAL EXACT FORMATS_

Comment: Technically, the date is not invalid, just as parameter to `Date()` ;-)

Comment: I meant from the point of the ECMAScript specs, but you are right.

Comment: Just to mention ([_ISO Date Format is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 standards mode_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx#ISO))

Answer (score -2):

Please Try this

```
new Date();
new Date(value);
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

You can learn about this function from following link

[**LINK**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: This is literally just copied from the MDN page and does not provide an answer